# What is the direction of the induced emf in this situation?

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

I know there have been plenty of variations of this asked before, but all of them I have seen don't really answer the question, or at least in a way that 'clicks' with me.

In terms of how i already understand it, i'll discuss by focusing on the positive charges:

Firstly, by the right hand rule, they go down initially, leading to there being a potential difference between the top and bottom. Hence, the emf is upwards facing. However, this seems to contradict what I am finding with Fleming's Right Hand Rule (what I am assuming is the right rule for this situation), since the motion is right and the field is out of the page, this would imply the current goes down, instead of up.

What I am missing here? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance[image: Image of moving conductor in magnetic field out of the page]

Answer (score 1):

> Firstly, by the right hand rule, they go down initially, leading to there being a potential difference between the top and bottom.

Yes...

> Hence, the emf is upwards facing.

No. Motional EMF is facing downward. What is facing upward is the electric field of the separated charges on the rod surface. When the rod moves with constant velocity through uniform magnetic field,  force due to electric field of the surface charges acts on any free charge and perfectly counteracts the electromotive force on that charge due to motional EMF; then charge stops moving along the rod, and surface charge density does not increase any further.

Comment: Thank you very much!